# How to write query SQL [ group by id order by date and reset value after nulll

Tags: sql, oracle

I try write a query in SQL (Oracle) that result will be in column `count`

I use analytic function `count(*)` but the result is wrong.

I would like get the result like in column counts. Column counts is reset if column payment is 0 or null. Otherwhise add one to value in column counts

Table with output that I would like to get (targetcolumns --> counts)
TARGET TABLE

| date | id | payment | counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210131 | 111111111 | 0 | 0 |
| 20210228 | 111111111 | 0 | 0 |
| 20210331 | 111111111 | 0 | 0 |
| 20210430 | 111111111 | 100 | 1 |
| 20210531 | 111111111 | 200 | 2 |
| 20210630 | 111111111 | 400 | 3 |
| 20210731 | 111111111 | 0 | 0 |
| 20210830 | 111111111 | 0 | 0 |
| 20210930 | 111111111 | 0 | 0 |
| 20211031 | 111111111 | 200 | 1 |
| 20211130 | 111111111 | 500 | 2 |
| 20211231 | 111111111 | 0 | 0 |

After write this code I get this result.

```
select 
    date, id, payment,
    count(payment) over (partition by id order by date) as counts    
from 
    table
```

This is the incorrect result I'm getting now:

| date | id | payment | counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210131 | 111111111 | 0 | 0 |
| 20210228 | 111111111 | 0 | 0 |
| 20210331 | 111111111 | 0 | 0 |
| 20210430 | 111111111 | 100 | 1 |
| 20210531 | 111111111 | 200 | 2 |
| 20210630 | 111111111 | 400 | 3 |
| 20210731 | 111111111 | 0 | 3 |
| 20210830 | 111111111 | 0 | 3 |
| 20210930 | 111111111 | 0 | 3 |
| 20211031 | 111111111 | 200 | 4 |
| 20211130 | 111111111 | 500 | 5 |
| 20211231 | 111111111 | 0 | 5 |

Comment: This is the *source*? What's the *target*, then? Which result do you expect (explained in plain English)? You said that you tried to write a query but it didn't work as you wanted it to. Maybe you should post it regardless.

Comment: Target is column counts(I FIX example Table). I try use analityc function(SQL Oracle) function count.

Comment: OK, but - what are you counting? Where did 0 from the 1st row come from? Or 1 from the 4th row?

Comment: I counting not 0 payment in row. If payment is null i fix 0. Counts is my target column.
I counting not null payment by id column ordering by date.

Comment: @MariuszLasecki, Please provide more info about your table data and the current wrong output, that will help fellow members to help you out, the provided info is not enough to fix your problem query

Comment: I provide more info to post

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you want to count the rows where payment is not zero? If that is the case, you can do it like this (using your query):

```
select 
    date, id, payment, 
    sum(case when payment = 0 then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id order by date) as counts 
from table
```

And don't name columns using reserved words (like date), it can be done but a really bad habit.

Comment: Hm, not really; expected result is contained in the 1st table (posted in question). Your query returns what the OP doesn't want.

Comment: My bad, didn't read carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test order by datum;

     DATUM         ID    PAYMENT
---------- ---------- ----------
  20210131          1          0
  20210228          1          0
  20210331          1          0
  20210430          1        100
  20210531          1        200
  20210630          1        400
  20210731          1          0
  20210830          1          0
  20210930          1          0
  20211031          1        200
  20211130          1        500
  20211231          1          0

12 rows selected.
```

Query that returns result you expect:

- `GRP` CTE: determine *groups* of rows depending on `payment` column value within each `id` group (I presume there can be others)
- final `select`: use `case` expression to set result to `0` if `payment = 0`; otherwise, use `row_number` analytic function

---

```
SQL> with grp as
  2    (select datum, id, payment,
  3       sum(case payment when 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by datum) grp
  4     from test
  5    )
  6  select datum, id, payment,
  7    case when payment = 0 then 0
  8         else row_number() over (partition by id, grp order by datum) - 1
  9    end rn
 10  from grp
 11  order by datum;

     DATUM         ID    PAYMENT         RN
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
  20210131          1          0          0
  20210228          1          0          0
  20210331          1          0          0
  20210430          1        100          1
  20210531          1        200          2
  20210630          1        400          3
  20210731          1          0          0
  20210830          1          0          0
  20210930          1          0          0
  20211031          1        200          1
  20211130          1        500          2
  20211231          1          0          0

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```